# How to write/draw over the figure with site specific locations in Latex

Tags: text-decorations

I wish to show some comment/text bubble on my picture in latex presentation. Kindly help me to write/comment on a included figure in latex.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) This question is very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559/86. Please take a look at it as the answers there might help you. If they do, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find the answers quickly. If they don't, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: Yes, the question is similar. The answer here is more simpler than answer there based on my requirement. What to do?

Comment: Given that the answer you got *isn't* at that other question and is quite different to those at that, and that it is sufficient for what you want, then do nothing more than you have done: accepting the answer.  It hadn't appeared when I wrote my comment, so you can ignore (most of) what I said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the picture environment described in section 5.2 of the [Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lshort-english). Use a `\put` command to position your figure, and another `\put` command to position the comment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(200,200)
\put(0,0){\framebox{\phantom{\rule{200pt}{200pt}}}} %Dummy box in place of an image.
\put(150,50){\hbox{Over here}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```