# Exporting Xfig picture

Tags: xfig

I have drawn a figure in Xfig and then I tried to export it into LaTeX picture so I can include it with my LaTeX code.
Among the forms, I have plotted circles, which have been exported as ... rectangles with rounded boxes (so the figure now in my LaTeX looks really ugly).

I have read over the internet that "Angle Geometry" option may solve the problem, but this functionality is only for some line forms.

Any help.

PS: Other exports format (EPS, SVG, ...) work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried drawing some concentric circles in xfig and exporting as a `LaTeX` picture.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
% \usepackage{pict2e}
\begin{document}
%Begin xfig output
\setlength{\unitlength}{3947sp}%
%
\begingroup\makeatletter\ifx\SetFigFont\undefined%
\gdef\SetFigFont#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \reset@font\fontsize{#1}{#2pt}%
  \fontfamily{#3}\fontseries{#4}\fontshape{#5}%
  \selectfont}%
\fi\endgroup%
\begin{picture}(1966,1966)(4418,-4944)
{\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\thinlines
\put(5401,-3961){\circle{900}}
}%
{\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\put(5401,-3961){\oval(1500,1500)}
}%
{\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\put(5401,-3961){\circle{450}}
}%
{\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\put(5401,-3961){\oval(1950,1950)}
}%
\end{picture}%
%end xfig output
\end{document}
```

[image: circles]

The issue lies with the picture environment, which is severely restricted. In particular, there is a limited set of circle sizes that can be drawn; see chapter 5 of the [Not so short guide to LaTeX](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lshort), or chapter 7 of Leslie Lamport's own book for more details. Indeed, in the log file, one finds the following:

```
LaTeX Warning: \oval, \circle, or \line size unavailable on input line 16.
LaTeX Warning: \oval, \circle, or \line size unavailable on input line 18.
LaTeX Warning: \oval, \circle, or \line size unavailable on input line 22.
```

Now, following @egreg's suggestion, one might try loading the [pict2e](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pict2e) package, but there is another complication. It seems that if one exceeds the maximum circle size in the original picture environment, then `xfig` uses an `\oval` command instead, so loading `pict2e` won't help (though it can change the result). Looking at the [xfig manual](http://xfig.org/userman/frm_printing.html), it appears there is no support for `pict2e`.

However, xfig can export graphics in many more modern formats, including `eps` and `pdf`. You can use these in your document instead; see chapter 4 of the [Not so short guide to LaTeX](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lshort) for details. It is possible to use `eps` or `pdf` graphics in a picture environment and place other items on top of them (details [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32663/2417)).

Comment: You probably avoid the warnings by loading `pict2e`.

Comment: @egreg --- Indeed, but the shapes still aren't circles. Quite why xfig chooses to draw a circle with the `\oval` command is a mystery that I am too tired to solve now.

Comment: @egreg --- Actually, I couldn't resist ... who needs sleep anyway?